# How do I calculate distance between origin and point on a chord in the unit circle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles

I have a chord connecting two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ on the unit circle. I would like to calculate the distance $(l_1,\,l_2,\, l_3, \ldots)$ between the origin $(0,0)$ and the point on the chord for "every" point on the chord. I have the arc-length and I set/choose angle theta.

I don't have the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the singular points on the chord only the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

A picture for clarification:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  To be honest, I would be do this totally analytically.  But there is a geometric law that would do it in one step.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind my "one step" comment.  The law would still be useful, but you'd need more machinery.  To do it analytically, just consider that if you control theta and p1, you control p2.  And you can express p1 and p2 in Euclidean/polar coordinates, in terms of theta.  And you can figure out the equation for the line between the points.  You probably want to parametrize that path by t on [0,1], the typical convention.  Then take the distance of a generic point |f(t)|.  There's a lot of steps to stitch together, but they should all be relatively clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to consider the issue (A and B) :

A) If the coordinates of points $P_k$ are $(\cos \theta_k, \sin \theta_k)$ for $k=1,2$, consider the barycentric expression :

$$\binom{x}{y}=(1-\lambda) \binom{\cos \theta_1}{\sin \theta_1}+\lambda\binom{\cos \theta_2}{\sin \theta_2} \tag{1}$$

taking all values of $\lambda$ between $0$ and $1$, you will browse all your chord.

Said otherwise, each point of the chord will be characterized by a unique $\lambda$.

Therefore the "generic" distance to the origin will be :

$$d_{\lambda}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

with $(x,y)$ given by (1).

**Remark :** In order to understand formula (1), two  examples,

- taking $\lambda = \frac12$ you get the midpoint of your chord,
- taking $\lambda = \frac34$, you are 3 times closer to $P_2$ than to $P_1$
  Besides, if you eliminate $\lambda$ between the two expressions $x=..., y=...$,  you will get the equation of the straight line, but I don't think that it is what you want.

---

B) Here is a different way.

Call $I$ the midpoint of your chord.

Let $(r_I,\theta_I)$ be the polar coordinates of $I$ (meaning in particular that distance $OI=r_I$.

If we consider now polar coordinates $(r_M,\theta_M)$ of any point $M$ on the chord, we have the simple relationship:

$$dist(O,M)=r_M=\dfrac{r_I}{\cos(\theta_I-\theta_M)}\tag{2}$$

(proof : definition of $\cos$ in right triangle $OIM$).

Answer (score 0):

You know that for any point in the plane, $$\tan\theta=\frac yx$$
The equation of the line is $$\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}$$
Here $P_i=(x_i,y_i);\ i=1,2$.You have a sytem of two linear equations, with two variables. Find $x$ and $y$, square them, add the squares and you get $l^2(\theta)$.